# Magento 2: Unable to upgrade Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento-2.1.2, magento-2.1.3

I'm trying to upgrade from Magento 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 on my Linux Server. On my Local WAMP it's working fine.

I'm upgrading in Developer Mode.

I got below error.

```
root@magento-2:/var/www/html/magento# composer update
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/symfony/filesystem%24c13f449735d971527daf30626fd921d452706653964a6736a4e50c29258b693d.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 302 Found)


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

**[SOLUTION]**

[Magento 2: Composer Update is Not Working [Failed to open stream: Connection timed out]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150849/magento-2-composer-update-is-not-working-failed-to-open-stream-connection-tim)

Comment: Have you try to upgrade magneto from admin panel? Easy way of upgrade magento is do it from admin.

Comment: Nope. This is the best way i use. Let me try that also

Comment: There was described the same problem: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1992#issuecomment-20869636 perhaps it will help you

Comment: Solution is: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150849/magento-2-composer-update-is-not-working-failed-to-open-stream-connection-tim

Comment: Please don't write "Solved" in the question. Mark the right answer as accepted instead or if the answer is in a different question, mark this one as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for info @fschmengler Can guide how to mark Question as Duplicate or Answer is here?

Comment: You should see a "close" link below the question where you can choose "duplicate" as close reason and enter the link of the original question. It is possible that you don't have enough reputation yet, in that case use "flag" instead and then select "should be closed"

Comment: In this case, I already did it